# Differential equations using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> A door is opened between rooms that hold $\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}v(0) = 30$ people and $w(0) = 10$ people. The movement between rooms is proportional to the difference $v - w$:
>   $$
>   \frac{dv}{dt} = w - v \quad \frac{dw}{dt} = v - w.
> $$
>   Show that the total $v + w$ is constant (40 people). Find the matrix in $\frac{d\vec{u}}{dt} = A \vec{u}$ and its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. What are $v$ and $w$ at $t=1$ and $t=\infty$.

I have never done any problems with two derivatives. (I know how to do with just one derivative, you get the eigenvector and eigenvalues and plug them in the formula). Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the two-dimensional vector
$$u(t)=\begin{pmatrix} v(t) \\ w(t) \end{pmatrix}$$
Its derivative is given by
$$u'(t)=\begin{pmatrix} v'(t) \\ w'(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} w(t)-v(t) \\ v(t)-w(t) \end{pmatrix}=Au(t)$$
where $A$ is the fixed matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
You can find $u(t)$ as usual by finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$. The coordinates of this vector are $v(t)$ and $w(t)$ which we are interested in.

Quick derivation: Eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $-2$ with eigenvectors $u_1=(1,1)$ and $u_2=(-1,1)$ for instance. General solution is then 
$$u(t)=c_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + c_2e^{-2t}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} c_1-c_2e^{-2t} \\ c_1+c_2e^{-2t} \end{pmatrix}$$
so that, by definition of $u(t)$:
$$v(t)=c_1-c_2e^{-2t}\hspace{1cm} w(t)= c_1+c_2e^{-2t}$$
where the constants can be determined from the initial conditions.

Comment: Do you mind actually deriving it? The part that I'm confused about is the final answer does not have any vector in it..

Comment: I've edited my post.